# Global import in javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, closures, global

Can somebody explain to me what this does in javascript?

```
 (function (x,y){}(x,y));
```

or this

```
  // global import
  (function ($, YAHOO) {
         // now have access to globals jQuery (as $) and YAHOO in this code
  }(jQuery, YAHOO));
```

I have never seen something similar in other languages like java or c++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`function(x, y) { }` is an anonoymous function.

`(x, y)` calls that function, passing `x` and `y` as parameters.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of the second code block is to make `jQuery` available as `$` (without defining `$` globally) and importing `YAHOO` in the local scope to make variable lookups a bit faster.

Besides that, it creates a new scope so any variables defined with `var` inside will not be global.

The first code block is often used in this way to create new variables, e.g. when you are in a loop and need to create a variable with the current `i` value for a callback:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert("number " + i);
        }, 1000 * i);
    })(i);
}
```

Without that new scope you'd have the *same* `i` everytime and thus alert "number 10" 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

The first one calls an anonymous function, which takes 2 arguments and doesn't do anything, with `x` and `y` as argument.

The second does the same thing. It uses $ as the first argument name, and passes jQuery as the argument value. It's thus possible, inside this function to use `$` to refer to the `jQuery` object. It's a way to alias variables to another name inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

C# has a similar concept, called a Lambda expression.

```
public static Func<int> Foo()
{
    int a = 1,
        b = 2;

    return () => a + b;
}
```

It's a generic, first-class function (by first class function, it is meant that the function itself is returned, not the result thereof) that is declared anonymously.

In this case, I also show you what's called a closure - the returned method encloses the 'local' variables a and b, allowing them to persist when Foo goes out of scope.  In many languages, anonymous methods implement closures.

Anonymous methods are really cool too - you can perform behavior injection, as in this benchmark method:

```
public static TimeSpan BenchmarkMe(Action timeThis)
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew()
    timeThis();
    sw.Stop;

    return sw.Elapsed;
}
```

You can pass an anonymous function that returns a TimeSpan into this method, which will perform a benchmark for a single pass against it.  Nifty, eh?